# Powershell to find value and create file

Tags: command-line, powershell, find

I am new to powershell, was hoping for some help. I am looking for a powershell command that will search through a file and find a string and create a file based on that string value that is found.

File "abc.txt" has a sentence of words in it that looks like this, **Logged into app\prog01**. But some times this file "abc.txt" will have different prog and number in it, like prog21 or prog58.

When the command runs, if the abc.txt has **Logged into app\prog58** in it, it will create a file simple named prog58 with no extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `Select-String` cmdlet, which is by default aliased as `sls`. This cmdlet allows you to match a regular expression and then extract the matched string. The full command goes something like this:

```
$(sls 'Logged into app\\prog[0-9]+' 'abc.txt' -all).matches | foreach { $fn=$_.value.split('\\')[1]; [System.IO.File]::Create($fn).close(); $fn }
```

Basically, for each instance of the string `Logged into app\\progX` (where X is one or more digits) that it finds in the file, it takes the stuff to the right of the `\` until it reaches the end of the digits, creates a file of that name, closes the file without writing to it, and echoes that name to stdout (you can remove the last part if you want).

Answer (score 0):

I know you asked for a PowerShell command, but what I am about to offer may suffice.

It will work in a standard Cmd.exe shell, which means you can also run it in PowerShell, and it will be backwards-compatible with older Windows operating systems:

```
TYPE abc.txt | FIND "Logged into app\prog58" >NUL && IF NOT DEFINED %ERRORLEVEL% (TYPE NUL >prog58)
```

I may be misunderstanding the question, though.  Could you clarify if this is exactly what you are looking for, or if you are looking to create a file with the name of `progXX` based on whatever text exists in abc.txt?

**Edit after clarification:** *The following is also Cmd.exe-compatible and not PowerShell-exclusive, so while it cannot be used as a one-liner, it could be called as a simple Batch script:*

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL && SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
FOR /F "tokens=1-2 delims=\" %%A IN ('TYPE abc.txt ^| FINDSTR /C:"Logged into app\prog"') DO (SET FILENAME=%%B)
SET FILENAME=%FILENAME:~0,6%
TYPE NUL >%FILENAME%
```

Caveat: this relies on `progXX` having exactly 2 digits, thus `progXXX` would not work.

Comment: Yeah, I am looking to create a file with the name of the progXX based on whatever is in abc.txt

Comment: @user4618954 - I have updated my answer to reflect your clarification. While it may not be exclusive to PowerShell, it will work fine in script form as .bat/.cmd/.ps1, etc.